# How to select interval of time or values range for timeseries data

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, time-series, data-analysis

I am working on time-series. which has two columns unit_time and traffic_load. In unit_time I have values from 0 to 7140. In traffic_load column I have different float values. I want to select the interval of time from 360 to 1000. When I try with the following code I am getting blank data_frame which has nothing. How can I select the interval of time. What will be the exact approach to select values range in specific column?

Actual data_frame
[image]

Here is the code that I am working with

```
df = data_frame[(data_frame['unit_time'] >= 360) & (data_frame['unit_time'] <= 1000)]
df
```

I am getting this Output
[image]

I am expecting to have interval of time from 360 to 1000 values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be mixing up `df` and `data_frame`. The following example works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = np.arange(7140)
loads = 100*np.random.rand(7140)

d = {'unit_time': times, 'traffic_load': loads}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = data_frame[(data_frame['unit_time'] >= 360) & (data_frame['unit_time'] <= 1000)]

df
```

Output:

[image]